# CSS parsing error when adding an image into scene

Tags: css, javafx

I want to put a background image into a scene but I always get an error message
*PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser parse* and 
*WARNING: CSS Error parsing file:/D:/Login/bin/login/Login.css: Expected LBRACE at [1,9]*

Here is a SSCE from my Login.java:

```js
package login;
 
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Login extends Application {
 
 @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
    
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Login.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();        
    }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
 }
}
```

And here is my a CSS from my Login.css

```js
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

.root {
     -fx-background-image: url("background.jpg");
}
```

Does it have to do with my current plugin? I use eclipse Luna and the WTP toolkit to work with style sheets.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS parser in recent JavaFX versions seems to choke on the `@CHARSET` declarations. If you remove that declaration, it should fix the problem.